# How to call java based wsdl webservice using ksoap2 from android client?

Tags: android, wsdl, android-ksoap2, wsdl2java

I am new to android.
I have to call java based wsdl webservice from android client using ksoap2.
Can any one help me?
I have try to call but getting XmlPullParserException.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class where I use ksoap

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import searchparams.MetaData;

public class RequestTools {

    public interface ResultListener{

        /**
         * 
         * @param result
         * @param mode also used for error
         */
        public void onReadable(String result, int mode);
    }

    private static KSOAPAsync mSearchAsync = null;

    public static final int ERROR_UNDEFINED = -1;
    public static final int MODE_CALCULATOR = 0;
    public static final int MODE_WEATHER = 1;

    public static void startGetWeatherData(ResultListener listener, String city){

        mSearchAsync = new KSOAPAsync(listener, MODE_WEATHER);
        mSearchAsync.execute(city);
    }

    public static void startGetAddition(ResultListener listener, String x, String y){

        mSearchAsync = new KSOAPAsync(listener,MODE_CALCULATOR);
        mSearchAsync.execute(x,y);
    }

    public static class KSOAPAsync 
        extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, SoapPrimitive> {

        private ResultListener resultListener = null;

        private int modeType = -1;

        public KSOAPAsync(ResultListener listener, int mode) {
            resultListener = listener;
            modeType = mode;
        }       

        @Override
        protected SoapPrimitive doInBackground(String... params) {

            SoapPrimitive result = null;

            switch(modeType){

                case RequestTools.MODE_CALCULATOR:

                    result = getCalculation(
                            Integer.valueOf(params[0]),
                            Integer.valueOf(params[1]));

                    break;

                case RequestTools.MODE_WEATHER:

                    result = getWeather(params[0]);

                    break;

                default:
            }



            return result;
        }

        private SoapPrimitive getCalculation(int x, int y){

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                    MetaData.Calculator.NAMESPACE,
                    MetaData.Calculator.METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("x",x);
            request.addProperty("y",y);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttptransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    MetaData.Calculator.URL);

            SoapPrimitive result = null;

            try {
                androidHttptransport.call(MetaData.Calculator.SOAP_ACTION,
                        envelope);

                result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                Log.i(TAG,""+result.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        private SoapPrimitive getWeather(String city){

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                    MetaData.Weather.NAMESPACE,
                    MetaData.Weather.METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("City", city);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttptransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    MetaData.Weather.URL);

            SoapPrimitive result = null;

            try {
                androidHttptransport.call(MetaData.Weather.SOAP_ACTION,
                        envelope);

                result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                Log.i(TAG,""+result.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static final String TAG = RequestTools.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SoapPrimitive result) {

            if(result == null){
                resultListener.onReadable(null,RequestTools.ERROR_UNDEFINED);
            }else{
                resultListener.onReadable(result.toString(),modeType);
            }
        }
    }

}
```